# How can I get rid of this "Auto Commands" message from vim?

Tags: vim

If I have this line in my vimrc

```
au VimLeave %bdelete
```

Then whenever vim starts it says

```
--- Auto-Commands ---
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I have that line there to empty the buffers from gvim, because new gvim instances have massive `:ls` output from previous runs. Notably, gvim doesn't actually produce this prompt.

Obviously I can set this instance up to only occur during gvim startup and not console vim, but I'd like to understand this rather than avoid it. Mostly I'm confused that `VimLeave` seems to cause things to happen on startup.

TIA
Altreus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that this is an incomplete `:autocmd` definition, so Vim attempts to list all `VimLeave` autocommands defined for the pattern `%bdelete`. You need to specify the *any file* pattern to make it work:

```
au VimLeave * %bdelete
```

Also, check whether you have `%` in your `'viminfo'` option; that one enables the saving and restoring of the buffer list you're complaining about. The `f` option of file marks may also result in buffers being restored; you could try `:set viminfo+=f0`.

Comment: Ah! You'd think it would tell you that your au was incomplete. As for the buffer thing - I didn't do anything specifically, but gvim remembers buffers and console vim doesn't. I'll check viminfo, thanks :) *Edit* hmm - they both have % but in console it doesn't seem to have the intended effect

Answer (score 1):

New Vim instances don't inherit the buffer list of the previous instance unless *you* add `%` to the `viminfo` option.

Setting that option to a sane value will remove the need for your broken fix. Reading the documentation before adding options to your config will prevent you from similar issues.

See `:help 'viminfo'`.